# Display a popup in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uikit

What I'm trying to achieve is this :
When a UISlider is scrolled , a small helper view should fades in displaying the current slider value .When the slider is released the helper view fades out . What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi mate just see the code of this example and also use this class for display popupview in iphone..

http://blog.chrismiles.info/2010/12/cmpoptipview-custom-popup-view-for-ios.html

i hope this help you..

:)

**Edited:**

```
-(void)addPopUpView{


    Yourview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    objMakeOfferView.view.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
        Yourview.alpha = 0.94;
        Yourview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }];
    objMakeOfferView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 80);///set frame which you required
    [self.view addSubview:Yourview];


}
-(void)removePopUpView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
       Yourview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        Yourview.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [Yourview removeFromSuperview];
    }];


}
```

also use different type of TransitionAnimation which you want..

:)